Modifier keys (such as Ctrl or Shift) not working properly
I'm experiencing a strange problem on Linux Mint 21.1. In some cases, the modifier keys like Shift and Ctrl are not applied as expected. Here's what's happening:

When I press Shift + letter, it sometimes outputs the lowercase
letter instead of the uppercase one. I need to press once again and
then it usually works.
When I use Ctrl + V to paste, it occasionally types a literal "v" instead of pasting the clipboard content. Same goes for Ctrl + C and other shortcuts.
The issue is intermittent — it doesn't happen all the time but is frequent enough to disrupt my workflow.
The issue affects all applications, including text editors, terminals, and web browsers.
Most probably it's software related since the issue becomes much worse when the computer is under heavy CPU load, but it also occurs under normal load conditions.

Any ideas what it could be?
